# What are some methods that Flash apps can communicate with each other?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, communication, communication-protocol

I'm developing an interactive system where two client flash apps will talk to a third server app. The clients will be sending some status information to the server. I think I need two way communication...haven't decided whether the server needs to send back any acknowledgements yet.

These will be applications and not .swfs that run in a browser.

So far the only method that I see are to make the server an AIR app (b/c AIR has a Server Socket class) and make the clients Flash projectors (b/c Flash has a Sockets class).

Are there other methods that I can use connect my apps together? These 3 machines will basically be living a few feet from each other and they will be on their own dedicated network.

**MORE INFO**

The machines will live within their own little private network. They won't be accessing the outside world.

Comment: I would go with AIR apps and use ServerSocket and Socket classes. Has worked well for me with 20+ machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had great success using AIR apps for this, again on a dedicated network.

I created a server application using the `ServerSocket` class, accepting connections on two different ports. Connecting to these different ports were 7 kiosk applications, and 20 display applications - When a user selected something on a kiosk it was relayed to the display applications via the server app which dealt with any conflicting user interactions.

Both the kiosk and display apps handled their own connections, with a timer continually checking `socket.connected`.

Comment: Good idea re: checking for socket.connected. Need to check and then re-establish connection if socket gets disconnected for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Adobe Cirrus (ex Stratus)

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/

It does exactly what you want to do.

Comment: These machines will live on their own private network...they won't be able to access the outside world, i.e. so they won't be able to connect to Cirrus.

Comment: you say: "The clients will be sending some status information to the server"! So use Stratus on your server.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into Flash Media Interactive Server, depending on the project's budget and how many client connections you expect.

I've used FMIS with great results in the past and the Developer Edition supports up to 10 simultaneous connections and it's license agreement allows for commercial use.  http://forums.adobe.com/thread/856736

Download link
https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flashmediaserver&loc=en_us

Edition comparison
http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/compare/

Plus, it's quite fun to develop with :)