# How to connect 2 known users in flex app together using rtmfp?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, rtmfp

How would you be able to connect 2 users ( that are known and have a user account on my site) in a flex app together using rtmfp?

```
I have a simple flex game app where I want 2 users to be connected to each other. 
There is a simple SQL database in the background for storing the users, 
but after this I'm unable to figure out how I would connect the 2 users.
```

Some thoughts:

- rtmfp generates a unique ID that you can use to connect 2 users together?
- Im looking for a good tutorial info resource or an example app that demonstrates connecting 2 users, or just an explanation

Thanks for any help or insights

Ilse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this post [What are some methods that Flash apps can communicate with each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125035/what-are-some-methods-that-flash-apps-can-communicate-with-each-other/9125438#comment11485645_9125438)

Adobe Cirrus is my recommendation. Good luck!

---

Adrian -- 
http://www.redcodelabs.com